# Azure backup lifecycle management

Tags: azure, backup

Looking for a link on Azure Backup lifecycle management or help file will also do or anyways to design the Backup Lifecycle management

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Backup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/) service provides simple, secure, and cost-effective solutions to back up your data and recover it from Azure. You can back up anything from on-premise data to Azure File Shares and VMs, including Azure PostgreSQL databases.

To start off, you can learn more about Azure Backup [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-architecture). This article summarizes Azure Backup architecture, components, and processes. While it’s easy to start protecting infrastructure and applications on Azure, you must ensure that the underlying Azure resources are set up correctly and being used optimally in order to accelerate your time to value.

To learn more about the capabilities of Azure Backup, and how to efficiently implement solutions that better protect your deployments, [detailed guidance and best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/guidance-best-practices) have been described to design your backup solution on Azure.

For additional reading, also refer to some [Frequently asked questions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq) about Azure Backup.